# What is the complexity of an SQL query that randomly selects a subset of rows from a database?

Tags: sql, big-o

## Introduction

I am using the following SQL query on an SQLITE3 database. I want to **randomly** select **N** rows that have an **id** `greater or equal` to a **randomly** generated number between `[1,...,max(id)]`. The table contains 40 Million rows. thus `max(id) = 40M`.

---

## SQL query

```
SELECT distinct tf_idf
       FROM MY_TABLE 
       WHERE id >= (abs(random()) % (SELECT max(id) FROM MY_TABLE)) 
       LIMIT L;
```

---

## Complexity

- The complexity of random() is `O(1)`.
- the complexity of  `(SELECT max(id) FROM MY_TABLE)` is `O(N)`.
- I still can't compute the complexity for `distinct tf_idf`

---

Comment: Max id is known to the database already as it is a unique index? so, the cost is linear. i.e .each random id is a constant time lookup (approximation). Do twice as many - it takes twice as long. The real world may not be so nice due to disk seek times etc. ;-/ All you are really doing is generating random lookups into an index. Which is exactly what it is for.

Comment: @RyanVincent yes. retrieving sometimes hundreds of lines is costly. Each string line is around (484 B)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL does not provide complexity guarantees.  The best we can do is talk about the lower bound of what's theoretically possible, and keep in mind that other factors may dominate.

> the complexity of  (SELECT max(id) FROM MY_TABLE) is O(N).

or O(log *N*), depending on your index, and whether or not it's used.  Or possibly O(1), if `max(id)` is treated specially.

The complexity of `distinct` is likewise opaque.  It implies a sort, which we can take to be O(*n* log *n*). But it's only O(*N*) if the data are already sorted, and cheaper still if they're known not to contain duplicates.

Looking at your query, I would approach your question this way:

- a binary search along an index on `id`, if extant
- a binary search along an index (putative) for output `tf_idf`
- *N* times, where *N* is a function of the cardinality of `id` and `tf_idf`

For example, suppose there is only 1 `id` and `L` is 2.  If the cardinality of `id` to `tf_idf` is 1:1 -- with or without an index on `id` -- the system will have to read all the rows in `MY_TABLE`.  If every `id` is unique, but they all map to the same `tf_idf`, an index would probably only add to the cost versus a linear scan.  If the cardinality is 1:1 and `id` is unique, then *N ~ L*: as the number of distinct pairs grows, the probability of randomly selecting a duplicate declines.